# When inserting data to a table, how can I know that inserting is successful or not?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, insert

if code=1, inserting is successful. if code=0, inserting is
unsuccessful. I couldn't this. I want to see this information on screen in android. I'm sorry for my bad english. I would be glad if you could help.

php code:

```
<?php
    $host='123.45.67.89';
    $uname='username';
    $pwd='password';
    $db="database";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $surname=$_REQUEST['surname'];
    $age=$_REQUEST['age'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("insert into table values('$name','$surname','$age') ",$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
        echo"hi";
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Java code:

```
insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            name=editText1.getText().toString();
            surname=editText2.getText().toString();
            age=editText3.getText().toString();

            String data[]={name,surname,age};

            new DoThatThingBro().execute(data);


        }
    });

}


    protected JSONObject addPost(String name, String surname, String age) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{

        String URL = "http://website.com/insert.php?name="+name+"&surname="+surname+"&age="+age;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
        s = status.getStatusCode();

        if(s == 200){

            HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject result = posts.getJSONObject(0);
            return result;


        }

        return null;
    }

    public class DoThatThingBro extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                json = addPost(params[0],params[1],params[2]);
                String data = json.getString("reuslt");

                return data;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: $r=mysql_query..... r here will contain results. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm

Comment: Please switch to MySQLi or PDO so that you can use bind variables in your SQL statements, especially as you don't escape or sanitize the data values that you're inserting

Answer (score 0):

Try some code like this in your php. call it when you want to see the table.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablename");
```

that will store the table in the $result variable.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['firstcolumn'] . " " . $row['secondcolumn'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

That will get all the data in the table as an array and print all results until there is nothing else to print.
Hope this helped. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After your comment the question is clearer.

Set your php to this:

```
$r = mysql_query("insert into table values('$name','$surname','$age') ",$con)
if (!$r) {
    echo "Insert failed: " . mysql_error());
} else {
    $flag['code']=1;
    echo "Successfully inserted " . mysql_affected_rows() . " rows";
}
```

And your java:

```
String URL = "http://website.com/insert.php?name="+name+"&surname="+surname+"&age="+age;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
try {
    String response = httpclient.execute(get, new BasicResponseHandler());
    Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man but I need java code to see this information on android screen.